# Remove Excel Duplicate Columns 123 , 123-1, 123-3

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am facing this problem where I want to remove duplicates in columns in Excel.

For example in 1 column I have these types of values:

### |Values|

|123|
|123-1|
|123-2|
|123-3|

**I want to have only the `123-3` left after I remove these rows.
Any solution to this?**

A short example of my issue:

[image: Excel Example of what i want to achieve]

Comment: Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then update your question. As it stands, we can't help you.

Comment: I posted a screenshot. I can't explain it in a more simple way.

Comment: Add a helper column containing only the portion of the string before the dash.  Then run `remove duplicates` on that helper column.

Comment: The image helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you split the values into 2 columns via using "Text to Columns" function (Date tab > Data tools).

[image]

Then copy the column of numbers before the horizontal line, paste to a new column (Such as G column from G1), remove duplicated data via "Remove Duplicates" function.

[image]

And then use the formula `=G1&"-"&MAX(IF($C$1:$C$7=G1,$D$1:$D$7))` in H1 to get the results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365, you can use

=INDEX(A1:A7, XMATCH(UNIQUE(LEFT(A1:A7,3)), LEFT(A1:A7,3), 0, -1))

Which filters for all unique three letter strings, then search bottom-up for those strings to find the latest one in the list. Might have to sort the list first.